# Can not work the build "flutter build apk" command, But "flutter build ios" can work

Tags: android, flutter, build

[image]

I am a beginner.
Currently I am trying to build my flutter app for iOS and android .
I can build successfully in ios by   “flutter build ios”.
But I have the following issue with "flutter build apk".
I will be very happy if someone can help to answer for the following issue (Ref attach img).

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-SG)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
Android Studio (version 3.5)
VS Code (version 1.42.1)
Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try
`flutter clean`

then `flutter pub cache repair`

if the problem still persists,

Check for `compilesdkversion` everywhere in the folder and match it with one in `android/app/build.gradle`

[Check here, same kind issue is closed in flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47122)

Comment: After clean and cache repair, I checked all "build.gradle" under  the Gradle Scripts and changed compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 in the build.gradle (Module: steams_channel) as you told. Now I can successfully build apks. Thank you very much, Yogesh Chawla.